# MVC Razor helper for bootstrap navbar

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I am trying to user Html Helper for bootstrap navbar, having example HTML like this:

http://razonartificial.com/themes/reason/v1.4.3/home_services.html

```
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>

 <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Pages</a>
                     <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left">
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="has_children">About us &amp; Team</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left">
                                <li><a href="page_about.html">About us Option 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="page_about2.html">About us Option 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="page_about3.html">About us &amp; Team</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>                                        
                                <li><a href="page_team.html">Our Team Option 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="page_team2.html">Our Team Option 2</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
---
---
</li>
</ul>
                </li>
 </ul>
```

I tried to make helper for this:

```
@inherits IdentityPre.App_Code.HelperPage
@using System.Web.Mvc
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html
@using IdentityPre.Models

@helper DisplayTree(System.Collections.IEnumerable model, int i, string addclass = "")
{
string dp = "";

foreach (Item element in model)
{

    if (element.ParentItemID == null)
    {
        dp = "dropdown";
    }
    else if (element.ParentItem.ParentItemID == null)
    {
        dp = "dropdown-submenu";
    }
    <li class=@dp>
        @if (element.ParentItemID == null)
        {

            @Html.ActionLink(element.PageTitle, "Details", "Items", new { @parentitem = "mycompany", @url = (element.Url) }, new { @class = "" })
        }
        else
        {
            if (element.ChildItems.Count() > 0)
            {
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="">@element.PageTitle</a>

            }
            else
            {
                @Html.ActionLink(element.PageTitle, "Details", "Items", new { @parentitem = (element.ParentItem.Url), @url = (element.Url) }, new
               {
                   @class ="dropdown-toggle"
               })
            }
        }
        @if (element.ChildItems.Count() > 0)
        {
            dp = "dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left";

            <ul class="@dp">
                @DisplayTree(element.ChildItems, i)
            </ul>
        }
    </li>
}
}
```

But result is not as expected. Nested nodes in menu are always open and all nodes in menu have right arrow icon.
The helper is called as following:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                @Helper11.DisplayTree(Model.ParentChildLanguageList, i)
</ul>
</div>
```

Any help! Thanks in Advance.